# extract coefficients from R lme model in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I need to extract the results of an R lme model called in python using rpy2. Extracting the coefficients with rx2 as follows :

```
model = nlme.lme(fixed=fixed, data=dfr, random=random, method="REML")
print model.rx2("coefficients")
```

Yields all the coefficients as follows:

```
$fixed
(Intercept)   log.var1 
  12.571692   -2.929928 

$random
$random$item
                (Intercept)    log.var1
12545646546 -5.189606e-16 8.276929e-16

$random$category
                 (Intercept)  log.var1
0001544848484/DLMX  -3.1909917  2.3938670
```

I want to extract the coefficient for `log.var1` in the fixed part of the model. I tried the following, but I got NULL

```
print model.rx2("coefficients$fixed[2]")
#gives NULL
```

How can I get the coefficient for log.var1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `rx2` corresponds to R's `[[`, which I understand to be identical to `$`.

With that in mind, you can access the item called "fixed" within "coefficients" the same way you are already accessing "coefficients":

```
# Python sequences are zero-based
model.rx2("coefficients").rx2("fixed")[1]
```

or

```
# R vectors are one-based (so 1+1=2)
model.rx2("coefficients").rx2("fixed").rx(2)
```