# How to access class attribute of an R object in python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, statistics, time-series, rpy2

I am using the vars package in jupyter notebook as so

For simplicity's sake the first couple of lines on your Jupyter notebook should be as

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Call function from R
import os
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
ggplot2 = importr("ggplot2", lib_loc = "C:/.../R/win-library/3.3")

# Import vars
Rvars = importr("vars", lib_loc = "C:/.../R/win-library/3.3")
```

and I have a dataframe say

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((108, 2)), columns=['Number1','Number2'])
df.head()
```

I coded

```
Model2=Rvars.VAR(df,p=3, type='const')
type(Model2)
```

and recieved the following

```
rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector
```

When coding with tuple

```
tuple(Model2.slots)
```

I received

```
('names', 'class')
```

Thus printing the names as

```
print(Model2.names)
```

Generates

```
[1] "varresult"    "datamat"      "y"            "type"         "p"           

 [6] "K"            "obs"          "totobs"       "restrictions" "call"
```

## My Question

All the above values are only elements of a list with class attribute 'varest' in R as described in

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf

on page 45

How may I access `varresult` from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. I received good help from

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/introduction.html

For illustration purpose, consider the trivial case of getting the variable `y` which represents the data matrix of the endogenous variables.

`.rx` and `.rx2` are new features in rpy2 as discussed in

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/changes.html

Although different, a similar question was answered in

[extract coefficients from R lme model in rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395476/extract-coefficients-from-r-lme-model-in-rpy2)

Based on my raised question

let us extract the variable `y` which represents the data matrix of the endogenous variables.

This can be achieved by the python attribute `rx2` as

```
A=Model2.rx2('y')
y=pd.DataFrame(np.array(A),columns=A.names[1])
y.head()
```

You will find that the `y.head()` is the same as the original dataframe `df.head()`

However, to extract the element `varresult` is a bit more complicated

I followed the similar argument as in

```
A=Model2.rx2('varresult')
print(A.names)

Output: [1] "Number1" "Number2"
```

Then

```
B=A.rx2('Number1')
print(B.names)

Output: 
[1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"         

 [5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"  

 [9] "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"
```

For example, to get the residuals of the regression from the first equation one may use the following

```
resid1=np.array(B.rx2('residuals'))
```

Comment: The documentation pages you are referring to are quite old. Check the links at https://rpy2.bitbucket.io for recent documentation.

Comment: @Igautier Thank you so much for your comment. But I am using a windows 10 and for some reason, I do not have access to rpy2 v 2.9 as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165123/install-rpy2-on-windows7-64bit-for-python-2-7

Therefore, I only have access to the documents I gave